# How to define an Action in an interface

Tags: vb.net, interface

How can I define the `StateChangedAction` in an interface? I have the same `Action` on different controls, so I would be cleaner to work with a single interface.

```
Public class MyControl
    Public StateChangedAction As Action(Of ControlState)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Fields cannot work in an interface, you must use a Property.   And you definitely ought to consider an Event.

Comment: The Property solution worked. Btw I didn't use Events because they were catched in different Threads and caused problems.